# Re: use a varable in place of the $5

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot v5.2 patchlevel 8 on a windows 10 pc.
Is there a way to replace the $5 with a variable like the stat1 one.
code
stat1 = “5”
plot filename u 1:(no=columnhead(stat1),$5) with lines lw .75 lt rgb "#1E90FF" title columnhead(stat1)

I have tried various ways of inserting in and combining the $5 in the varable  without any success.
I have also tried searching the web for a solution without any sucess
Peter

Comment: `column(stat1) `

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now